# Is it possible to persist psycopg2 connection more than 24 hour. I tried but I could not execute successfully

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have created database connection as below code. My question is basically is it possible to persist connection more than 24 hours. What my problem is current that if this code is running into application for more than 24 hours and if I don't do any insert or update on SQL from other process. Later after 24 hours even if there is new records in tables from other process. This code below return me before 24 hours value, which it executed last 24 hours back.

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

class Database:

    def __init__(self, DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD,
                 DATABASE_PORT, DATABASE_NAME):
        self.host = DATABASE_HOST
        self.username = DATABASE_USERNAME
        self.password = DATABASE_PASSWORD
        self.port = DATABASE_PORT
        self.dbname = DATABASE_NAME
        self.conn = None

    def connect(self):
        if self.conn is None:
            self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host=self.host,
            user=self.username,
            password=self.password,
            port=self.port,
            dbname=self.dbname)

    def rows_to_frame(self, query):
        self.connect()
        return pd.read_sql(query, self.conn)

    def fetchall(self, query):
        self.connect()
        with self.conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute(query)
            records = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return records

    def fetchone(self, query):
        self.connect()
        with self.conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute(query)
            records = cur.fetchone()
        cur.close()
        return records
```

The folder structure is as follows

```
Application
    --> pgconnection
        | --> __init__.py
        | --> db.py
    --> Source
        | --> main.py
```

For example:

`__init__.py`

```
from pgconnection import db

print(db.execute('select * from emp')
```

case 1:
record in emp table before 24 hours -

```
---------------------------
id  | name   | salary      |
---------------------------
1   | Sam    | 6000        |
---------------------------
2   | Adam   | 5000        |
----------------------------
```

and result of above code:

print(db.rows_to_frame('select * from '))

```
---------------------------
id  | name   | salary      |
---------------------------
1   | Sam    | 6000        |
---------------------------
2   | Adam   | 5000        |
----------------------------
```

case 2:

After 24 hours new data added into emp table from other process. If I execute the query again since object is created

```
---------------------------
id  | name   | salary      |
---------------------------
1   | Sam    | 6000        |
---------------------------
2   | Adam   | 5000        |
---------------------------
3   | Ada    | 5600        |
---------------------------
4   | Stephen | 7899       |
---------------------------
```

On running main.py it is still returning result as

```
---------------------------
id  | name   | salary      |
---------------------------
1   | Sam    | 6000        |
---------------------------
2   | Adam   | 5000        |
----------------------------
```

instead of

```
---------------------------
id  | name   | salary      |
---------------------------
1   | Sam    | 6000        |
---------------------------
2   | Adam   | 5000        |
---------------------------
3   | Ada    | 5600        |
---------------------------
4   | Stephen | 7899       |
---------------------------
```

what could be the reason? I am not able to solve the issue. Please someone guide me where I am making mistake your input is valuable.

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be Postgres but something about your code. Are both processes connected to the same database, or is one perhaps connected to a leader and one a follower? Is one or both processes in a transaction and they have not yet committed? Is there any default `where` clause limiting your results to a single day?

Comment: Holding a connection open that long is a bad idea.  Especially since you do not seem to be committing transactions. A connection should last for the minimum time necessary to get the work done and committed.

Comment: the other process is inserting into same table of same database where the above code is connected. There is no such default where clause. If I rerun the above package it works well but only when it is not restarted gives this issue.

Comment: That is because you are not committing the transactions. Under that scenario each session(connection) can see it's own changes but not the changes in the other session. The worse problem though is that by keeping a transaction open(uncommitted) you are unable to `VACUUM`(clean up) data that has to persist until it determined whether the uncommitted data is being committed or rolled back. DO NOT leave transactions open for a long period of time when it is not needed.

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver I also believe connection should not be ideal for more than one minute but how to auto kill session after one minute without manually closing in code for example in my code  `def rows_to_frame(self, query):` I am opening connection but I don't want to add `self.conn.close()` instead it should auto close after the interval.

Comment: No you don't want to auto close either. That will quite possibly leave incomplete or no data. Do  open connection, run transaction w/commit and then close connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my research and exploration on database connection and persisting connection. It is actually not recommended to open connection for long duration, instead the session should be closed as soon as read and write operation is completed else the connection error you might get as -

```
to many client error
```

and if you are trying to work with python OOPs for database connection then in that case if you are not closing the connection by default if client is ideal for long then you connection will be either auto closed else it will cache in python and even if you try calling any methods it will return you cache results.

So, the best you can do for less number of iteration to database connection is divide your data into partitions and for each partition create connection and process the operation and then successfully close the connection. This you can repeat with other partitions too.

Comment: nonsense. if true such feature like prepared_threshold in psycopg3 would not exists.